# How to compare specific elements of an array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to compare elements of an array of ints 8 elements long (array[]) add up the elements in sets of 2, then divide by 2 for the avg, eg array[0] + array[1] / 2 and assign the result to a new array 4 elements long.. Specifically, I want to compare them in sets of 2 to see if either / or both are  less than 40, if either is less than 40, I add them both up and divide by 2 for the average, and assign the array with the minimum out of (40, array[i]).. however if they are both above 40 I still add both elements and divide by 2 but assign the array element[i] with the number I get, not bothering with a minimum calculation

Heres what I have so far

```
   for (int i = 0; i < array.length ; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] < 40 )
        {
            array2[j] = Math.min(35, array2[j]);
        }
    }
```

The if statement is correct I think, but the boolean argument is far from it. Array[] = the original 8 element array... array2[] = the calculated and averaged array 4 elements long. Many thanks

Comment: I find your explanation confusing. Can you give us an example of what should happen, with example input data and expected output data?

Comment: @NickG eg, i have an array of 8 elements, array[] = {22,44,52,36,35,41,63,24} .. I want to compare every 2 sets of numbers, in this case, 22 and 44, then, 52 and 36, then 35 and 41... if any one element is less than 40, I want to add both elements and divide by 2 for the average of those two elements, and take the minimum value, either 40, or the average of the two elements, eg 22+44=66. 66/2=33.. Math.min(40, 33), so it takes 33 and assigns it to the 1st elements of my new array2[]

Comment: however if both elements are above 40, then just add them together and divide by 2 and assign that number, not bothering with a minimum calculation

Comment: Updated answer, let me know if I captured the logic correctly? I changed the logic to "if both elements are greater than or equal to 40, then just add them together..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean? Hopefully I understood the question.

```
for (int j = 0; j < array2.length; j++)
{
    double avg = (array[2 * j] + array[2 * j + 1]) / 2;
    if (array[2 * j] < 40 || array[2 * j + 1] < 40)
    {
        array2[j] = Math.min(avg, 40);
    } else {
        array2[j] = avg;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this captures the logic you described(?)

```
int[] test = {
    22,44,
    52,36,
    35,41,
    63,24
};
double[] newarr = new int[test.length/2];

for (int i = 0; i < newarr.length; i++){
    newarr[i] = (test[i*2] + test[i*2+1]) / 2;
}
```

Gives:

```
[33.0, 44.0, 38.0, 43.5]
```

Correct?

Comment: Not quite, 22+44= 66, 66/2 = 33... math.min(33,40)=33, correct. 52+36=88, 88/2 = 44. 44 > 40, so result added to array should be 44. 35+41= 76, 76/2=38... math.min(38,40)=38, correct.. 63+24=87, 87/2 = 43.5, 43.5 > 40, so result should be 43.5... hope ive cleared myself up, sorry for bad explanation, english is not my first language :(

Comment: Ok, minor update. Now? Changed datatypes to double, to capture decimals.

Comment: Um... I think the logic to check for <40 is redundant! I've removed it, and I still get the correct results! :P